# 2d boolean array is mysteriously changing its states

Tags: java, arrays

I'm implementing a tetris game, and generally the placement of pieces works fine. However occasionally when placing a piece, an entire column of the 2d array representing the game state will fill. eg:

from this:

```
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|  X XX   XX|
```

to this:

```
|       X   |
|       X   |
|       X   |
|       X   |
|       X   |
|       X   |
|       X   |
|       X   |
|       X   |
|       X   |
|       X   |
|       X   |
|       X   |
|       X   |
|       X   |
|       X   |
|       X   |
|       X   |
|  X XXXXXXX|
```

Where X's are tetris blocks.

By checking the total number of blocks at various points, I've narrowed it down to this section:

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < world.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        if (world[i][j]) {
            total++;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("total1 = " + total);

// add piece into environment
for (int i = 0; i < pieces[p.piece - 1][p.rotation].length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < pieces[p.piece - 1][p.rotation][i].length; j++) {
        // if there is a piece block here
        if (pieces[p.piece - 1][p.rotation][i][j]) {
            world[depth + i][p.position + j] = true;
            System.out.println((depth+i) + ", " + (p.position + j));
        }
    }
}
total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < world.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        if (world[i][j]) {
            total++;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("total2 = " + total);
```

This is the output for that previous example:

```
total1 = 5
17, 7
18, 6
18, 7
18, 8
total2 = 26
```

As you can see, the only point where the world array can be updated is only changed 4 times, yet afterwards, the world total has grown massively.

I cannot work out why this happening.

Oh, and the pieces array is just a constant 4d array

EDIT:

After testing a lot, I think it has something to do with my code for deleting rows, which is straight after the previous code:

```
boolean fullRow;
    latestCleared = 0;
    // check for completed lines
    // for each row
    for (int i = 0; i < world.length - 1; i++) {
        fullRow = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if (!world[i][j]) {
                fullRow = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (fullRow) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                world[i][j] = false;
            }
            for (int k = i; k > 0; k--) {
            world[k] = world[k - 1];
            }

        }
        latestCleared++;
    }
```

When I comment out the:
    for (int k = i; k > 0; k--) {
    world[k] = world[k - 1];

The problem doesn't occur. Just don't understand how this could be affecting it.

Also, It occurs of the same number of iterations regardless of which move combinations are fed in.

Comment: I see 4-dimensional arrays, that's too complicated for me. When it get's that complex, I try to brake it down into simpler structures and errors like this disappear from alone.

Comment: Thats not really the problem though. The real issue is the impossibility of only changing 4 states in world, yet the total grows by 21

Comment: Huh. Weird. What about putting calculating and printing of `total` into the inner loop (but outside of `if`)?

Comment: Just tried this on a different example:    
    total1 = 12
    total2 = 12
    16, 10
    total2 = 29
    total2 = 29
    17, 10
    total2 = 30
    18, 9
    total2 = 31
    18, 10
    total2 = 32
    total2 = 32

Comment: You can make sure that variables "width" and "world.length" are not changing in between, that is you are now searching in a larger part of the "world"-state?

Comment: @Matthias I search the whole of the word state each time, and the posted code is exactly as it appears in the program, so I'm not sure how it could change.

Comment: Just asking because the "width" variable is not declared in your example. So may be it is modified by some of the code you ruled not to be responsible for the observed behaviour.
The code you are showing "logs" every modification of that array's state. As no magic is going to happen, the source must be something else.

Comment: Fair enough. I just checked it, and neither width nor world.length ever change for all the iterations, thanks anyway

Comment: Maybe a concurrent access problem. Do you have any other thread executing at the same time? Maybe you are sharing the world array and other thread is modifying its values...

Comment: How you first allocated your arrays? maybe something in pointers. do you have any other affectations like world[i]=pieces[x][y][z] which would be vera bad?

Comment: It's not easy to follow you. First you show some code with an example and show the total, before and after adding a piece. Then you edit your problem and say that the problem is when you suppress a full row. That part wasn't participating in the total calculation. And in your first example, as there is no full row, the lines you are commenting wouldn't change anything as they shouldn't be executed.

Comment: @eternay I agree the fullrow shouldn't affect the rest of the code, but the problem isn't there when the aforementioned code is commented out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the suppress part of your code, you have a problem:

```
for (int k = i; k > 0; k++) {
    world[k] = world[k - 1];
}
```

What you are doing there is copying references of rows, instead of copying the values contained in the preceding row. You should do something like:

```
for (int k = i; k > 0; k++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        world[k][j] = world[k - 1][j];
    }
}
// Adding a new blank row on the top of the world
for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
    world[0][j] = false;
}
```

This code will copy in a row values (and not references of row) contained in the preceding row.

Just to clean your code, you can suppress the part:

```
for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
    world[i][j] = false;
}
```

as you will copy the values of the preceding row in the values of this one.

I suppose that in your example, you suppressed rows before adding the piece that generates the problem. As references of rows are completely unpredictable, it is giving you unpredictable behaviour.

I hope that this simple modification will solve the whole problem, but check in your project if you have similar code.

EDIT: I'm pretty sure that all your rows, except the last one, are actually pointing to the same reference. So, when you add a piece with at least one element in the 2nd row, this element will be repeated in every single row till the top of the world.

EDIT2: You can print the references of the rows to confirm the problem:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < world.length; i++) {
    builder.append(world[k]).append("\n");
}
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```